# ¿Como puedo eliminar contenido de un array en un .txt C?

Tags: c

Tengo una función para añadir clientes mediante un array, estos clientes se almacenan en un .txt.(como puedo mostrar los clientes en el txt con saltos de linea)
Una vez añado los clientes quiero poder eliminarlos y para ello creo la función eliminar clientes la cual debe buscar el dni del usuario y eliminar el usuario completo. Ej: 4042923H, nombre antonio. Buscas el dni 4042923H y elimina tanto el dni como el nombre.

**[El código completo esta en el siguiente enlace:](https://pastebin.com/xaJ61THK)**
https://pastebin.com/xaJ61THK

**La función con la cual añado clientes es la siguiente:**

```
void aniadirCliente()
{

    if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0'){
        printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
        gets(nom_archivo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
        archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
        if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            system("cls"); //En windows limpia pantalla
        }else
        {
            int i;
            printf("\n\nArchivo cargado correctamente.|\n");
            for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
                fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
            }
            for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++)
            {
                if(clientes[i].dni[0]=='\0')
                {
                    //Crear un nuevo cliente, lo mismo que antes los espacios con _
                    puts("DNI:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", clientes[i].dni);

                    puts("Nombre:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].nombre);

                    puts("Apellidos:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                    puts("Direccion:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
            fclose(archivo);
            system("cls");

}
```

**Y la funcion para eliminar clientes** :clientes[i].dni, clientes[i].nombre, clientes[i].apellido, clientes[i].direccion.

```
void eliminarCliente(){

 if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nom_archivo);
            //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
            archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
            if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            }else{
                int i, y;
                char delcliente;
                for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
            fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
        }
                printf("Introduce el dni del cliente que deseas eliminar");
                scanf("%s", &delcliente);
                if(delcliente==clientes[i].dni){

                    printf("Cliente Eliminado");
                    //How to delete all of the client
                }
                else{
                    printf("El dni introducido no coincide");
                }

                }
        }


}
```

Comment: Espero que puedas resolver las dudas que tienes. Mientras tanto pregunto si puedo copiar el código para estudiarlo mejor (estoy aprendiendo programación) y adaptarlo posteriormente a un proyecto que tengo. Saludos.

Comment: te puedo dar dos recomendaciones posibles para tu proyecto, una es que leas todo el archivo y lo guardes y empieces a hacer una lectura hasta encontrar el dni y lo ingreses de nuevo
la otra forma y creo que podría ser mejor es que al final de cada usuario pongas un identificador el cual te diga si es un usuario activo o eliminado, de esta forma solo tendrias que buscar al usuario y cambiar el identificador por otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es volver a escribir toda la información en el archivo omitiendo colocar la correspondiente al DNI a eliminar:

```
rewind(archivo); // Regresa la posición del archivo al inicio
if (delcliente == clientes[i].dni) {
    for (int pos = 0; pos < max_clientes; ++pos) {
        if (pos != i) 
            fprintf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);     else
            fprintf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s", "", "", "", "");
    }
}
```

No obstante creo que hay un problema en la que escribes y lees cadenas del archivo. Tu programa tiene la estructura típica que apoya la lectura/escritura de acceso aleatorio excepto por una cosa: La lectura y escritura no se hace de forma binaria sino en forma de caracteres lo cual muy probablemente no va a funcionar como esperas.